# How to replace some patterns with whitespace in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, file-handling, perlscript

I'm having a file in which there are lines containing some patterns as

`XX3 DB3 DBB1 VDD VSS VSSS VDDS inverter params: ln=.045u wn=0.5 mm=mm'

`XX4 DBB1 DB3 VDD VSS VSSS VDDS inverter params: ln=.045u wn=.12u

`XX14 DBB1 DB_TBY VDD VSS VSSS VDDS inverter params: Mpar =(Something))

I need to replace these lines as

`XX3 DB3 DBB1 VDD VSS VSSS VDDS inverter

`XX4 DBB1 DB3 VDD VSS VSSS VDDS inverter

`XX14 DBB1 DB_TBY VDD VSS VSSS VDDS inverter

that is I want to delete everything after params, It can be anything, till the newline.

```
    foreach(@lines){
     $_ =~ s/params: .*?[a-z,A-Z,),0-9,mm,m]'/ /g;}
```

But here everything is deleting but it should end with ' . As I have no idea about what all patterns can be present , this technique is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your regex is too complicated (and, therefore, too likely to be wrong). If you want to delete everything after `params:` then just do that.

```
for (@lines) {
  s/params:.+//;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the single quote at the end, do:

```
for (@lines) {
  s/params:.+/'/;
  ...
}
```